# How to make this calculation faster?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization

So I have an issue that I will explain:
I have a set of images that come from an experiment, each pixel of these images has 3 values associated which depend on the position (in case you wonder this is a diffraction experiment). What I would need is the intensity of the pixel, but as a function of these three values. The way I'm currently implementing it in python is with a bunch of for loops that find the pixels that have values within a narrow range and summing them together and saving this as a point in my new "space". Here is a basic implementation with some duummy values:

```
import numpy as np


def MaskApply(HKLvals, h, k, ll, dh, dk, dl):
    ans = (
        np.where(HKLvals[2].flatten() < ll + dl, 1, 0)
        * np.where(HKLvals[2].flatten() > ll, 1, 0)
        * np.where(HKLvals[1].flatten() > k, 1, 0)
        * np.where(HKLvals[1].flatten() < k + dk, 1, 0)
        * np.where(HKLvals[0].flatten() < h + dh, 1, 0)
        * np.where(HKLvals[0].flatten() > h, 1, 0)
    )
    ans = np.reshape(ans, HKLvals[2].shape, order="C")

    return ans


data = np.random.rand(120, 1000, 500)  # this is a collection of 120 images each 1000x500

# This is read by a file in my actual code
HKLvals = np.ones((120, 3, 1000, 500))  # These are some values connected to the images each of the 1000x500 pixels has three values. for the 120 images
H, dh = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000, retstep=True)
K, dk = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000, retstep=True)
L, dl = np.linspace(0, 5, 100, retstep=True)
outData = np.zeros((len(H), len(K)))

for i in range(len(L)):
    l = L[i]
    for j in range(len(H)):
        h = H[j]
        for t in range(len(K)):
            k = K[t]
            maskArr = np.zeros(np.shape(data))
            pixel_number = 0
            for m in range(np.shape(data)[0]):
                mask = MaskApply(HKLvals[m], h, k, l, dh, dk, dl)
                pixel_number += np.count_nonzero(mask)
                maskArr[m] = mask
            maskArr = maskArr.astype(bool)
            outData[j, t] = np.sum(data[maskArr]) / pixel_number
    print(outData)  # of course in reality this is saved in an .h5
```

This is the gist of my code ATM. I'd love if anybody had any input on this and could point out some efficiency mistakes, or perhaps a different algorithm to do this that maybe I'm not thinking about.

I suppose the easiest way to improve the efficiency would be to stop using Python and convert to something more performing like C++ or Julia. I'm also looking into that, but I'm very not well versed in those so in the meantime it would be great if anybody had any input.

Thanks to all who will read.

EDIT: fixed the code which is now running properly

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see where the hotspots are?

Comment: Uhm,,, how would I do that? I know that for my data each "k" loop takes about 4s.

Comment: See e.g. https://realpython.com/python-profiling/ for a good tutorial.

Comment: Also, please make sure the code you've pasted here can be run. (Currently, it doesn't work.)

Comment: https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene works well for profiling codebases that make use of numpy

Comment: looks a bit like you're doing a convolution, could you not just use numpy's `convolve` or the faster version in [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html)?

Comment: In what sense a convolution, sorry? I'm not sure I see it.

Comment: I'm struggling to follow all your indicies around the place so it might not be, but it looks like you're just getting the mean of nearby pixels.  you can use the optimised convolution algorithms to do this (assuming you've got a regular grid, which your example seems to)

Comment: Its not a convolution because the mask is not always the same shape centered in each point, but rather the collection of all pixels with a particular configuration of HKL values

Comment: For one, you end up doing `HKLVals[m][...].flatten()` a whole lot – you could memoize those values.

Comment: @LourençoMonteiroRodrigues  it's pretty opaque code!  am also wondering whether `pixel_number = np.count_nonzero(mask)` is deliberately overwriting `pixel_number` or if that's a bug and it should be accumulating the counts?

Comment: @SamMason definitely opaque! that whole block is being ovewriten, so I agree with the bug theory, only the last iteration is being used for something

Comment: if you just want things to going faster without changing the code much you could try using https://numba.pydata.org/?  it can do pretty magical things if you're somewhat careful.  I'd also suggest passing `dtype` into your ndarray constructors (e.g. `np.zero`).  e.g. you're creating `maskArr` as an array of 64bit floats then converting them to `bool`s as the end, why not just keep them as bools the whole time?

Comment: @SamMason At that point, the multiplications should also become `&` masking :)

Comment: Yeah, that's part of the reason why I'm asking for help around. I'm technically the best programmer in my group lol. pixel_count is overwritten because the number of pixel for each iteration is different so I want to normalize by the number of pixels (the original code has an if that handles the case where there's no pixel)

Comment: @mmonti can you explain what data and HKLvals are? is data the images and HKL an additional 3D set of information for the corresponding pixels?

Comment: So data is a collection of n images each one about 1000x500 pixels. They come from an x-ray diffraction experiment, so each pixel in the images has 3 values that I can calculate (h, k, l) . For each of the n images I have a matrix that links each pixel to its 3 values (which is currently stored as a 3x1000x500 array). Then of course I have one of those matrices for each of the n images.

Comment: @LourençoMonteiroRodrigues also yes the pixel count should be a +=. Sigh. There's a reason I hated computers when I was a student.

Comment: Ok, so your goal is to have the average pixel intensity for each HKL configuration, and you want this for each image, or to aggregate the intensity for all images?

Comment: No, in a sense the 3 values define another "space" so I want to rebuild this sets of images in another sets of images where I can plot the intensity as a function of 3 coordinates that are not pixel, pixel, n, but H, K, L.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given our conversation in the question comments, I propose the following solution, that addresses a few points mentioned by other people, namely:

- Create the masks several times (here you create the masks just once for each image)
- flatten and reshape several time (no need to do that, numpy can handle comparisons in multi-dimensional case)
- mask combination using appropriate tools
- result aggregation (you can just compute the average, no need to keep track of number of pixels selectede)

here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import product


def process_image(image, HKL_values, H, K, L, dh, dk, dl):

    Nh, Nk, Nl = map(len, (H, K, L))

    h_mask = np.array(
        [np.logical_and(
            HKL_values[0] > h,
            HKL_values[0] < h + dh
        ) for h in H]
    )
    k_mask = np.array(
        [np.logical_and(
            HKL_values[1] > k,
            HKL_values[1] < k + dk
        ) for k in K]
    )
    l_mask = np.array(
        [np.logical_and(
            HKL_values[2] > ll,
            HKL_values[2] < ll + dl
        ) for ll in L]
    )

    intensities = np.zeros((Nh, Nk, Nl))
    for h, k, l in product(range(Nh), range(Nk), range(Nl)):
        mask = h_mask[h] & k_mask[k] & l_mask[l]
        intensities[h, k, l] = np.average(image[mask])
    return intensities

# Load data
data = ...  # load images
HKL_vals = ... # load HKL values for those images

# define HKL steps
H, dh = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000, retstep=True)
K, dk = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000, retstep=True)
L, dl = np.linspace(0, 5, 100, retstep=True)

for i in range(len(data)):
    image = data[i]
    vals = HKL_vals[i]

    result = process_image(image, vals, H, K, L, dh, dk, dl)

    # save result for that image
```

It uses the process image function to create the masks once, and then uses the itertools function `product` to create all possible combinations of H, K, and L masks (for each of them value steps), selecting those corresponding pixels from the image and averaging their intensity. This produces a 3D-array with indices along H, K, and L steps, each with the average intensity of pixels that correspond to that particular HKL configuration.

Note also that x_mask will be a collection of all masks for the dimension x, and x_mask[i] is the mask corresponding to the i-th step of dimension x

## Important note before running

As numpy stores booleans in a byte (8bits), the memory consumption of pre-calculated masks is 8x heavier than what this answer considers. As pointed out by @SamMason, `h_mask` will occupy ~500MB! If you have RAM limitations (in the end the masks alone will demand ~1.05GB, and you still need essentially 4D images@ 1000x500), you will inevitably have to break down the solution, pre-computing the smaller masks, and then computing the other masks as needed (just the body of adapted `process_image`:

```py
l_mask = np.array(
    [np.logical_and(
        HKL_values[2] > L[l],
        HKL_values[2] < L[l] + dl
    ) for ll in L]
)

intensities = np.zeros((Nh, Nk, Nl))

for h in range(Nh):
    h_mask = np.logical_and(
        HKL_values[0] > H[h],
        HKL_values[0] < H[h] + dl
    )
    for k in range(Nk):
        k_mask = np.logical_and(
            HKL_values[1] > K[k],
            HKL_values[1] < K[k] + dl
        )
        for l in range(Nl):
            mask = h_mask & k_mask & l_mask[l]
            intensities[h, k, l] = np.average(image[mask])

return intensities
```

Note that the precomputed masks are used in the inner-most for-loop, which is the one that runs the most times.

Comment: Uhm, It's getting late here I'll try to have a look and digest this

Comment: Looks much nicer!  Will presumably use quite a bit memory keeping all those things precalculated.  Might be worth just precalculating l_mask and calculating the other two as they're needed, CPU time shouldn't be impacted much but it'll use a lot less RAM

Comment: I think the `map(len, H, K, L)` should take an iterable as a second elemeent so `map(len, (H, K, L))`, no? using python 3.11. Also the code seems to work well and it's definitely faster than mine I'll run a couple of tests on my data to check I get equivalent results and I'll accept this answer

Comment: @SamMason keeping the dimensions of the provided example, each "big" mask set should take up ~60MB (it is boolean), with the 3 masks being less than 130MB in total. I think that should compensate recalculating the masks all the times that the combinatorial nature of the problem requires

Comment: Yeah this gives me the same results and it's significantly faster. Marked as accepted. THank you!

Comment: @LourençoMonteiroRodrigues I was calculating ~0.5GiB for `h_mask`, i.e. `np.zeros([1000, 500, 1000], dtype=bool).nbytes / 2**20`?

Comment: @SamMason you are correct, for some reason numpy stores booleans as 8bit (1byte), which explains the 8x difference between our estimates...  I will add that note to the answer

Comment: Yes, I think the RAM requirements still limit this, it's partly the same reason why I don't think it would improve that much parallelizing either this or my original code. I'm currently running it on a machine that doesn't have to do anything else, so for my purpose it is still much faster anyway.

Comment: @LourençoMonteiroRodrigues didn't expect you to rewrite it!  but, yup, interesting our different expectations coming from other languages!  I was also assuming OP was potentially using larger images / more steps for `H`/`K`/`L` that might significantly increase the requirements.  1GB of RAM still isn't that much these days, but certainly approaching the region where it's worth noting

Comment: Just checked some timings, and `np.average(image[mask])` takes about 5ms for me, while `np.average(image, weights=mask)` is only 2.  `np.average(np.ma.masked_array(image, ~mask))` gives the same answer, but at 8ms is the slowest.  hence using weighted average might make things twice as fast